# jQuery sortable and array resort

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an array of elements: `markers` and a table which updates it's rows to populate with the data stored within `markers`. `markers` itself houses an object `marker` which has a latitude and longitude amongst other things.

When I populate the table with the details from the `markers` array I give each row an ID based on `i` as it loops through.

On this table I have jQuery sortable. I am looking for a way to re-order my `markers` array each time the rows are sorted, so that the position of the item in the array is actually it's sort order value. That way, I can simply loop through the array at any time and see it's most up to date order.

So far I have the table generating as should and the `markers` array populated. I am even able to grab back the order of the rows after shuffling them around, at the moment I store them in an array `orders` and just alert, this works (ie. 0,1,2 > dragged to resort > 2,0,1). I was hoping for a way of now using the set of values in `orders` to resort my original `markers` array.

I thought it would involve creating a temporary array `markersTemp` with which to store the values saved in `markers` but in the new order, except I'm not sure how to loop through to save each one. Anyone done anything similar?

Comment: Show your code, so I can implement that.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, I did get it solved but maybe you can answer my question in the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function resort() {
    var order = []; // Get the order of the new rows
    $('#createMapDirections tbody tr').each(function(i, elem){
        order.push(markers[getId($("td", elem))]);
    });
    markers = order;
    updateAll();
}
```

Old procedure:

1. Create a new list `order`
2. Loop through the current rows in the table.
   Store the IDs at the current rows in list `order`
3. Create a new list `markersTemp`
4. Loop through list `order`
   Get the ID at position `i` in list `order`.
   Let `markersTemp[i]` be the element in `markers` (referred at the old position through `id`)
5. Reset `markers`
6. Set `markers` to `markersTemp`

Optimized:

1. Create a new list `order`
2. Loop through each row in the table.
   Push the element, as referred by the index as returned from `getId()` in `order`
3. Overwrite `markers` by `order`.

Comment: Works a treat! As for the position of the `id`, it is in fact on the table row, but I use `getId()` elsewhere passing in an element inside one of the table cells. `getId()` itself actually looks like this ((added to my answer instead due to formatting))

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, apologies for wasting everyones time! 5 more minutes and I got it solved. For others with the problem, here's my entire function called after a sortable dropped event.

I wouldn't say it was entirely over though. I would be very interested to know if this is the most efficient/tidiest way to do this. I am aware there is an array .sort() function built into javascript, could this be used instead?

```
function resort() {

    var order = new Array(); // Get the order of the new rows
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        order.push(getId($('#createMapDirections tbody tr').eq(i).find('td')));
    }

    var markersTemp = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var id = order[i];
        markersTemp[i] = markers[id];
    }

    markers.length = 0;
    markers = markersTemp.slice();

    updateAll();

}
```

**Edit:**

Ok so my table on the page is laid out like so:

```
<table><tbody>
    <tr id="row0"><td></td></tr>
    <tr id="row1"><td></td></tr>
    <tr id="row2"><td></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

getId() simply grabs the id of the TR and runs a little regex to get only the number. When they are resorted then the order might be something like: row2, row0, row1. I store this order in `orders` (a temporary array) and populate `markersTemp` (another temporary array) with the values of `markersTemp` but in the new order.

```
function getId(button) {
    return $(button).parents('tr').attr('id').replace(new RegExp('\[A-Za-z]+'), '');
}
```

Comment: Define `getId`. And yes, there's an `Array.sort` function. I have created several sorting algorithms already. Just post the relevant code, and I will adjust one of these for your case.

Comment: I've posted an optimized script. Your code example does not equal your code: Your example mentions `id` to be attached to a row, while the code alleges the ID to be a property of a cell.